# Why page url changes after PUT method in Web API?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am using Web API in a MVC Website. This is my Update action in the API controller:

```
public HttpResponseMessage PutProduct(int Id, ProductModel model)
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = null;
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        model.ProductId = Id;
        if (model.Update())
            response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created);
    }
    return response;
}
```

I call it using JQ AJAX from a partial view which is loaded in the Index.cshtml page. The code works fine and the index page does not get called again, instead, the new list is populated in the partial view itself. I am not calling Index page again. But after the response, the page url changes to show like this:

```
http://localhost:54820/Products/Index?ProdName=Chicken+Soup&Category=Chinese&Price=20
```

This is my AJAX:

```
function updateprod(product) {
    $.ajax({
        url: uri + '/' + product.ProductId,
        type: 'put',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify(product),
        statusCode: {
            201: function (data) { //accepted
                loadlist();
            }
        }
    })
    .fail(function (xhr, textStatus, err) {
        alert(err);
    });
}
```

I want the URL to be like this, like what it was initially:

```
http://localhost:54820/Products/Index
```

Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the response headers.

It seems that [your response has a location header used by the user-agent to redirect to URL indicated in the response](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.2.2).

Besides that you should use 201 status-code for created resources, for update is better to use 200 (OK), how you can read in the [w3c docs](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.6).

Hope it helps.